# SSMS clean output window with sql instruction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

How can i clean `output` window in `SSMS` using `t-sql` syntax? Is it possible ?
Do you know any workarounds ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot - I wasn't the OPer, but I have a script that builds a system then populates it with data. That process produces dozens of panels on the "results" tab. My last statement calls on a procedure that has been created - as a means to check the results of the script. It would be nice to clear out the dozens of un-required results before the one statement that will give me useful information.

Answer (score 10):

This is not possible to do within the context of a single execution of whatever is in the Query pane. T-SQL commands are not interpreted by SSMS. They are sent to SQL Server to be processed. Only a `GO [execution_count]` statement (batch separator, `GO` being the default but can be changed) and a subset of the SQLCMD commands -- `!!`, `:exit`, `:quit`, `:r`, `:setvar`, `:connect`, `:on error`, `:error`, and `:out` -- are captured and processed by SSMS (and are not sent to SQL Server).

Also, there aren't even any internal SSMS commands to clear either the Results tab or the Messages tab.

So, if there are any results being returned, they will be in the Results tab at the end of the execution no matter what.

BUT, after that execution ends, you can manually clear both the "Results" and "Messages" tabs by highlighting an empty line (or even just a space on a non-empty line) and hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

OR, depending on why this is being requested, you can hide the "Results" and "Messages" tabs by hitting <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL + R` hides the display results grid.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this does not clear the results - if you type `CTRL + R` again it will show the results window with the previous results still available.

Answer (score 0):

just run a query that returns nothing

```
select 1 where 1 = 2
```

Comment: This returns a results panel that is empty. It does not clear the Results tab of prior result panels. More specifically, if I have: `select 1; select 2; select 1 where 1 = 2;` I will then see three panels on the results tab. That last `select` did not clear out the Results tab of the results of the first two queries.